# Can't send email using javamail and jdk 12

Tags: jakarta-mail, javax.activation

I used to send emails with javamail and Java 8.

Now that I upgraded to Java 12 I get the `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javax/activation/DataHandler`.

I added the `javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar` and now I get `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/activation/registries/LogSupport`.

This is because `javax.activation-api-1.2.0.jar` doesn't have the `com.sun...` package that previous versions had.

What jars should I put on my project to properly send and email with java 12? And where to find them?

There are a lot of confusing sources like:

https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/javax/activation/javax.activation-api/1.2.0/

https://eclipse-ee4j.github.io/jaf/

https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/java-archive-downloads-java-plat-downloads.html#jaf-1.1.1-fcs-oth-JPR

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need the implementation jar file, not the API jar file.  Use [this](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.activation/javax.activation/1.2.0/jar).

Comment: There is no attachment. Jakarta mail/activation is equivalent to java mail and java activation framework?

Comment: Sorry, editing error, fixed above.  The Jakarta version is identical to the javax version, and you can find it [here](https://search.maven.org/artifact/com.sun.activation/jakarta.activation/1.2.1/jar).